# Displaying all values of arraylist to a textview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, random, textview

I am developing an app where i have to generate random values from an arraylist `obj` and save the generated values to `rndmObj` arraylist. I need to then display all the values of `rndmObj` to a multiline  textview `tvObjectList1` on the screen. But while opening the app, it crashes with the usual message of "unfortunately the app has been closed."

I know there's a certain problem with the code. So logcat wouldn't be helpful.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level);


    prepareObjList();
    randObjFunc();
   }}

    private void prepareObjList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //adding string values to arrayList for tvObjectList1
    obj = new ArrayList<String>();
    obj.add("bowTie");
    obj.add("key");
    obj.add("grosshoper");


    //adding imageViews to objImg arrayList
    objImg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    objImg.add(R.drawable.level1_bowtie);
    objImg.add(R.drawable.level1_key);
    objImg.add(R.drawable.level1_grasshopper);
}


final Random randomGenerator = new Random();
ArrayList<String>obj;
ArrayList<String>rndmObj;
public String item=null;
private void randObjFunc(){
    int index=0;
    while(index <10){
        item = obj.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(obj.size()));
        rndmObj.add(index, item);
        obj.remove(obj.indexOf(item));
        index++;
    }
    dispRndmObj();
}


private void dispRndmObj(){
    for (int i=0; i<rndmObj.size();i++){
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvObjectList1))
        .setText(rndmObj.get(i).toString());
    }        

}
```

there's no syntax error and app installed perfectly. all the initializations are done of all variables, arraylists etc
I'm hoping for quick and some useful suggestions, guidance and code snippet.

Comment: `obj` is never initialized. You are operating on `null`.

Comment: Also, the tags are very vague. You should add the language and platform - java and android?

Comment: obj is initilized in onCreate method. and yes i am developing for Android through java on Eclipse.

Comment: updating the question with needed code. revisit it after few sec.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever initialize obj and rndmObj?

Try

```
ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> rndmObj = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also

```
randomGenerator.nextInt(obj.size())
```

Will throw IllegalArgumentException if obj is empty (eg because you never populate it, which you don't seem to.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, There are couple of things that are faulty in your code, first of all initialize `obj` and `rndmObj` as

`ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> rndmObj = new ArrayList<String>();`

After that you will get `IllegalStateException` most probably on `obj.size()` as it will return zero which is not expected by `nextInt(n);` method. So, then you will have to probably insert some values in `obj` or depends what you want to do further. Once you do this, you will figure out what to do next. Hope this helps, You can post comment if got stuck anywhere. :)

Comment: @SaadAhmedKhan You still have not initialized `rndmObj` in your updated code dude.

Comment: Also in your question, you stated your variables as `arraylist1` and `arraylist2` but in code you actually you are using `obj` and `rndmObj`. Please try to maintain code structure  in your question. Just an additional suggestion :)

Comment: ok i have updated the question. and i have tried the same architecture with a variable instead of "rndmObj" arraylist. and display the value of that variable on the textview. and it perfectly works. 
now what i want to know is what is the procedure to view or display all the values from the arraylist  to a multiline textview as in my case "tvObjectList1".

Comment: I am facing the issue with the dispRndmObj() method. is it good enough to complete the logic.

Comment: You still havn't initialized `rndmObj` in your code in question. Well, as you are saying, I am assuming that before `dispRndmObj()` method, all is working fine and you are getting all values in `rndmObj`. To get all values printed in your textView just replace your method by this and try:
`private void dispRndmObj(){
  TextView textView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvObjectList1));
     for (int i=0; i<rndmObj.size();i++){
         textView.setText(textView.getText() + rndmObj.get(i).toString());
     }        

 }`
Hope it helps, if yes, accept answer as accepted.

Comment: You are updating textView's value every time you enter into for loop, So your code is not able to display all values. What I have done is first get current value of textView and then append it with next value in array list, as clear from code I posted in above comment.